# Best approach for Android 2d drawing apps

Tags: android, 2d

I have a question about making a drawing app for Android. What is the best approach? I would like to make an app that keeps all objects available for the user to work with.

Do I have to use opengl for that? I would like to use the canvas drawing approach since it is easier to use, but perhaps this is not possible for what I want.

And how do I keep all object available for the user? Do I need to use large arraylists?

Thanks in advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android developer guidelines are pretty clear.  If you need to draw 3d and/or multiple frames per second, then OpenGL is probably best.  For a "paint" style drawing app, `Canvas` ought to be fine.

Comment: Ok and how about keeping all objects available to users? I saw that people use a bitmap to cache objects to but I dont think that's an option for me or is it?

Comment: If your drawings are to be compositions of bitmaps (like Photoshop), then a layer-based database of attributed bitmaps is what you need.  If your drawings are geometrically based (strokes, polyines, polygons, curves, ovals, groups, transforms, etc.), then you need a hierarchy of corresponding objects, which naturally takes the form of a directed acyclic graph or DAG. A full-featured graphical editor can quickly become a large project, and making a really good one is difficult.

Comment: If you now any information sources where I could start with (websites, books) please let me know. I am very interested.

Answer (score 0):

you can use opengl for complex 3d painting , and the canvas for 2d painting .

you can also use third party libraries that are easier to use , such as [libgdx](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) and [andengine](http://www.andengine.org/).

another alternative is using [renderscript](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/02/introducing-renderscript.html) .